# How can I create a single partition from three different disks to install Windows on it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, raid

I have 3 disks: 1TB, 512GB and 512GB. Is there any way to create a single 2TB partition and install Windows 10 on it? Data safety is not important.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean install Windows on *one* drive, and then *combine all logically* into a single drive? See https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-combine-multiple-hard-drives-with-windows-storage-spaces

Comment: Why? Windows does not require 2TB of disk space to install (afaik)

Answer (score 3):

What you want is called "Disk Spanning" and is a feature of windows.

It is accessed by disk management or diskpart.exe.  I am not sure about third party tools to do this but I bet they do exist.

To extend two or more drives into a single volume using the command line, open a command prompt as an administrator and type diskpart.

If you don't have an operating system yet, this can be done from windows installation media.

1. At the DISKPART prompt, type list volume. Write down the number of the simple volume you want to extend to another disk.
2. At the DISKPART prompt, type select volume . This selects the simple volume number you want to extend to another disk.
3. At the DISKPART prompt, type list disk. Write down the disk number to which you want to extend the simple volume.
4. At the DISKPART prompt, type extend [size=] [disk=]. This extends the selected volume to disknumber and makes the extension size = size megabytes (MB).

There are MANY MANY tutorials on how to do this if you search for "windows disk spanning".

The information above came from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/575497/extend-spanned-volume) and [here](https://www.minitool.com/lib/spanned-volume.html).

Comment: While Windows supports disk spanning does it support being installed to a partition that spans multiple disks?